# How to detect exact location of mouse click on sprite in scratch

Tags: mit-scratch

I would like to detect the exact location of the mouse click within the 3x3 grid displayed on the screen. How can this be done in MIT scratch? Any suggestions?

Comment: Can the "mouse x" and "mouse y" blocks in the sensing category help with what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for the response....to some extent "mouse x" and "mouse y" will help but we need more than that. Imagine having 9 boxes on the screen and you need to identify the click of the mouse on a particular box.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this.
You could create 9 sprites, hide, and use the *When this sprite clicked* event... 
...but it would be a whole lot of unnecessary sprites.
Or you can do the following:
As @PullJosh said, you can use the mouse x and y blocks. Just do some math:
You know that the stage goes from X: -240 to 240, Y: -180 to 180.
Just put that into some code to detect ranges, below is a link to a project that is an example of this:
[This project](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/320116204/)
(Note: This assumes the grid boxes are the same size.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry for the delayed response. We dd something similar but using lists to store X location and Y location. We can write the coordinates to list at the time of the creation. But its bit challenging when we use clones.

Comment: CatDev, please share your mail id if possible,

Answer (score 1):

````
when greenFlag pressed
forever
  if <mouse down?> then
    set (lastMouseClickX) to (mouse x)
    set (lastMouseClickY) to (mouse y)
  end
  wait until <not<mouse down?>>
end```
````

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple if you want to involve 2 variables in this:
All you really need to do is to set the mousex position to a variable and the mousey position to a variable after the sprite detects a click on it. Here is an example:[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LAvM.png]